# CPAN Module Installation Fails

Tags: perl, cpan, hp-ux

Trying to install certain CPAN modules on HP-UX (May 2017), but getting an error:

```
# cpanm ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
--> Working on ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
Fetching file:///home/users/root_user/CPAN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30 ... OK
! Can't configure the distribution. You probably need to have 'make'. See /.cpanm/work/1515577528.15913/build.log for details.
```

But, looks like Perl is set to use gmake.

```
# perl -V:make
make='gmake';
```

make is installed on the system. How do I resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Build Log File

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7043 on perl 5.008008 built for IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi
Work directory is //.cpanm/work/1515577528.15913
You have LWP 5.820
Falling back to Archive::Tar 1.40
--> Working on ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
Fetching file:///home/users/root_user/CPAN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30.tar.gz
Entering ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Configuring ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.30
Running Makefile.PL 
Using included version of CPAN::Meta (2.143240) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of Parse::CPAN::Meta (1.4414) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of CPAN::Meta::YAML (0.011) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of File::Temp (0.22) as it is newer than the installed version (0.16).
Using included version of ExtUtils::Manifest (1.70) as it is newer than the installed version (1.46).
Using included version of JSON::PP (2.27203) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of ExtUtils::Install (2.06) as it is newer than the installed version (1.33).
Using included version of CPAN::Meta::Requirements (2.131) because it is not already installed.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Warning: the following files are missing in your kit:
        't/liblist/win32/di
        't/liblist/win32/space
Please inform the author.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.121_08)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0.8 ... Yes (3.12)
Checking if you have Pod::Man 0 ... Yes (1.37)
Checking if you have File::Basename 0 ... Yes (2.74)
Checking if you have Encode 0 ... Yes (2.12)
-> FAIL Can't configure the distribution. You probably need to have 'make'. See /.cpanm/work/1515577528.15913/build.log for details.
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using `cpan` instead. In my experience it can often install a module successfully when `cpanm` fails. After all, people are likely to test their install script only with `cpan`. If that fails, try starting `cpan` and then using `look ExtUtils::MakeMaker` followed by `perl Makefile.pl`; `gmake`; `gmake test`; and `gmake install` (if the tests succeeded, or at your own risk) as described in [`perlmodinstall`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is `gmake` in your PATH?

Comment: gmake was not installed. After installing this worked fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gmake was not installed. After installing this worked fine! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this trouble with CPAN

The key in your error "You probably need to have 'make'."

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Will install makefile.pl

Strange that something essential is not installed by default?